# Form validation with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I was creating a form with validation

here is the  js file is : http://pastebin.com/Ahy4dbsS

php file : http://pastebin.com/5B1hMK49

the problem is when I submit the form without clicking on any text boxes,
no validation happens, so i changed the js file so that the first text box will be focused on page load. 
but when that text box is validated (ie. click outside of the form) and form can be submitted without validation. how can i validate all the text boxes on page load?

Comment: here is the html used : http://pastebin.com/z3rGsd1Q

Comment: Where did you get `validate.js` from? Doesn't that say how to use it?

Comment: I know how to use it, but the above mentioned problem is a bug.

Comment: I suppose you could always start out with the Submit button disabled so you can't submit the form until it passes validation. But with three separate code listings it's impossible to see how they all work together. A single jsfiddle or a real URL would make things easier.

Comment: suppose i started with the submit button disabled, then when click on first input box and input the correct text , then click any where in the page except the form , it will validate the entered text box and will enable the submit button. only way idea i can imagine is to validate all text boxes on page load, is it possible?

Comment: Make every required field required. An empty required field won't validate.

Comment: check out http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleHomepage

Answer (score 0):

Better use a variable ex: `var flag=0;` and for every condition increment the flag as `flag=flag+1;` do this in all conditions finally make a condition:

```
if(flag>0){return false}else{return true}
```